# A method for standardizing URI/URLs in Ruby in a forgiving manner

Tags: ruby, http, url, uri

I'm trying to find a method to take a URI/URL string from a user and determine a working, canonical form (or failing if the resource isn't valid). Simultaneously, it should also verify that the URL exists. So we're checking for both valid "syntax" and also existence.

For instance, a string like `google.com` should be turned into `http://www.google.com`, and a string like `google.com/insights` should be turned into `http://www.google.com/insights`. A string like `http://thiswebsitedoesntexistatall.com` should return some sort of error or exception.

I believe a portion of the solution may likely be calling an HTTP `get_response()` method and following redirects until I get a `200 OK` status.

It seems like the `URI.parse()` method is not forgiving of leaving off the `http`. I realize I could write a simple thing to try adding `http` in front, etc., but I was hoping there was some existing gem or little-known library function that would be really forgiving about URLs and canonicalize them for me.

Both the built in `net/http` and `HTTParty` seem to be too strict for what I'm looking for. Is there a nice way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some problems with what you're asking for:

- A URL parser shouldn't assume the value passed in is HTTP, when FTP and many other [protocols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Official_IANA-registered_schemes) are equally valid. If you know the protocol is likely to be HTTP, then you need to add the protocol.
- If you try to connect to a site and follow redirects until you get a 200 response, you've only proven that the URL resolves to a valid page of some sort. That 200 could be an error-page returned because the one you want is a dead link or invalid, or that the site is temporarily down. To prove otherwise means you have to have some intimate pre-knowledge about the page you're looking for, such as specific content to search for.
- Assuming the URL is good after you follow the redirects, is not quite safe. Many sites add on all sorts of session data to the URL, so what could start as a simple and clean URL can resolve to a long and convoluted one.

I'd recommend you look at the [Addressable::URI](http://addressable.rubyforge.org/) gem. It's much more full-featured than Ruby's URI. It won't make the decisions for you, but at least it will give you a more complete API and can rewrite/normalize URLs. Cleaning them up and/or determining if they are good is still left as an exercise for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Regarding your first point -- I completely agree. I think other protocols *should* be accepted, that's why I want to avoid just shoving http in front. That being said, at the end of the day http is likely all I'm actually interested in. Regarding the second -- if the page was missing, wouldn't I get a 404 instead of a 200? I would assume that a 200 response would imply that it's a valid page and that it exists, but other response codes should be used otherwise. The point you raise about session data is an interesting one... I'll have to think on it. Thanks!

Comment: Whether a site returns a 404 or a 200 depends on whether they let the HTTPd return the error as what it is, or if they intercept it and redirect you to one of those "friendly/kinder and gentler" error pages telling you something was wrong and don't do the correct thing of returning the 404. A 200 is fine for humans, but [code has a hard time dealing with it](http://gsitecrawler.com/articles/error-404-200.asp). So "should" depends on who we're dealing with. Unfortunately, we, as developers and users of their content, usually don't get a say in it.

Comment: Just as a FYI, I'm basing my responses on a lot of hard-won knowledge dealing with sites and spidering and writing web-site analytic code... somewhere above 200 different spiders and tools. There's RFCs and specs and then there's reality and we have to program for reality, to deal with the output of untrained or ignorant page developers.